# is there any agora.io php sdk available for live streaming

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, sdk, agora.io

I am making a live streaming web application in laravel.
I want to use agora restful api's in php (laravel) but unfortunately there is no agora sdk available for php (laravel).
i have downloaded agora web sdk that is in react and nodejs. sdk is running but when i try to make broadcast it's showing this message "undefined media"

Answer (score 2):

What are you using PHP for? Token Generation? If yes, here's what you're looking for: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Gaming/token_server_php?platform=PHP

Agora works fully and solely on the client side eliminating the need for a server.

If you need a simple broadcasting application: https://github.com/digitallysavvy/agora-web-broadcast-demo.

Documentation: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/start_live_web?platform=Web

**EDIT**
Now that page has gone, please use the following page:-
https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Gaming/token_server#token-generator-libraries

You can find core code and sample apps for many different languages including PHP